# How does .next work when storing a new element on the stack data structure? [Java]

Tags: java, stack

I'm learning to implement a Stack and I'm struggling to understand what .next REALLY means. I've seen it in many data structures and it's obvious what its purpose is until I actually ask myself if it is a keyword or how it functions. It looks like it is an object but it seems to be acting like a pointer (like in a LinkedList) to each of the `item` objects that are created.

Please help in any way you can to shed some light on my confusion!

```
class Item {
    intdata;
    Item next;

    public Item(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class Stack {

   private Item top;

   public void push(int data) {
       if (null == top) {
           top = new Item(data);
       } else {
           Item item = new Item(data);
           item.next = top;
           top = item;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: *It looks like it is an object but it seems to be acting like a pointer (like in a LinkedList) to each of the item objects that are created.* You are not confused. That is 100% correct (well, it **is** an object).

Comment: It's not clear what you're confused about, please explain it better. Each `Item` has a field `next` which is of type `Item` and is a reference to another `Item`. What's not clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: If you understand how a linked list works, a stack shouldn't be too mysterious:  it's just a linked list that you only access from one end.

Comment: And, no `next` isn't a keyword: its the name of a member field of your `Item` class.  You could have called it anything you wanted: `link`, `previous`, `boogabooga`, whatever, the point being it's a programmer-chosen name, not a language-imposed reserved word or keyword.

Comment: I thought that "next" was some kind of method or keyword from a library that meant "look at next address" but then I saw the instantiation of "Item next" and didn't understand that it is an object that somehow assumes a functional ability of a pointer. (I hope I worded what I"m trying to say properly)

Comment: Technically, `Item next;` in the `Item` class is declaring a member field `next` which is of type "reference to `Item`".  If you're familiar with C++ references (e.g., `Item&`), it's the same general idea.

Comment: I'll have to read up more of C++ references, I seem to be lacking some understanding in object orientated programming. I just looked it up and there is apparently a difference between a reference and a pointer so thank you for the new information to learn

Comment: Please don't, unless you want to be even more confused. @KevinAnderson was imprecise. References in Java are like c++ pointers only the pointer is hidden. Java doesn't have anything equivalent to c++ reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think about this, if you have two initial *raw data 1 and 2*. And, on the other hand, I tell you to map all the natural numbers as `Item`s and then put them into a stack.

Considering, you might just come up with let us say, two `Item` objects currently unrelated as -

```
Item item1 = new Item(1);
```

and

```
Item item2 = new Item(2);
```

and then as you put them into the `Stack`, you push `item1` and you would eventually push `item2`. *There could similarly be N number of data that you might have pushed.*

And now to make you a little smarter, I would ask you to remember while you `pop` an element from that `Stack` as to what could be the `next` element possible, just to see if we might even need to pop more or not from that stack. [Let's say need be to display only elements greater than 5]

That is where the relation between the two items would become useful. You make one item ***point*** to the next while pushing them into the stack to keep a reference of the same. And so you do:-

```
item2.setNext(item1); // using setter for 'next'
```

Which eventually means while accessing `item2` you can actually be aware of the next `Item` it points to i.e. `item1`.

***PS***: The same implementation as `item2.setNext(item1)` is generalized in your code's `push` method which accepts a data and creates a new instance of `Item` every time its called.